# I can't add and delete each product individually into favorite list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I want to add more than one product into the favorite screen and delete each product from there separately, But when I click on add to favorite button I can only add one product and if I add another product the product replace the previous one NOT added on.

Context Code

```js
const initialState = {
  products: ProductData,
  cart: [],
  FavoritesList: [],
};
 
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE':
      const product = action.payload;

      const index = state.FavoritesList.findIndex(
        (item) => item?.id === product?.id
      );

      if (index !== -1) {
        return {
          ...state,
          products: state.FavoritesList.filter((_, i) => i !== index),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          products: state.FavoritesList.concat(product,),
        };
      }

    case 'DELETE_FAVORITE_PRODUCT':
      return {
        ...state,
        products:state.products.filter((item)=> item?.id === product?.id)
      };
              
    case 'CLEAR':
      return { cart: [] }
           
    default:
      throw new Error(`unknow action.${action.type}`)
  }
}
```

Favorite Screen Code

```
const Faviroute = () => {
  const { favorites, products } = useCart();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const Clear = (index) => {
    dispatch({ type: "DELETE_FAVORITE_PRODUCT", index });
  };
 
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}
    >
      {(products.length === 0) ?
        <View>
          <Text>Just add the items you would & place your order here.</Text>
        </View>   
      : <View style={{flex:1,}}> 
          {/*Card Container*/}
          <ScrollView>
            <View>
              {products.map((item, index) => (         
                <View key={index}>  
                  <Image source={item.image} />
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Clear(item)}>
                    <Image source={icons.love} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              ))}       
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Can anyone can help me figure out how I can easily add every single product separately into the favorite and delete each favorite product from favorite list separately?

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong, but don't you want to change the `FavoritesList` field from the `state`? It looks like you're changing the `products` list instead.

Also, it looks like in your `Faviroute` you're mapping over `products` instead.

Comment: There is no code where you are using ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE. Favorite Screen Code only dispatches DELETE_FAVORITE_PRODUCT.

Comment: Also, the logic in DELETE_FAVORITE_PRODUCT is wrong. You are checking for "equals to" in filter. You should filter out based on "not equals to" condition.

Comment: @CristiNica [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) creates a new array, how is this not an immutable update? It's functionally and logically identical to `[...currentArray, newElement]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like the `ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE` action to ***only*** add a product to favorite list one-by-one, and for the `DELETE_FAVORITE_PRODUCT` action to remove a product from the favorite list one-by-one then I suggest the following refactor:

1. Make sure the `DELETE_FAVORITE_PRODUCT` reducer case correctly accesses the action payload to get a defined product object to remove.
2. Ensure the adding/removing of favorites is operating on the `state.favorites` array ***and not*** the `state.products` array that is the "source of truth" of all products that *can* be favorited.
3. You are passing the currently mapped `item` to the `clear` handler, make sure to consistently name this argument so it's clear what is being passed.

Code:

```js
const initialState = {  
  products: ProductData,
  cart: [],
  favorites: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE':
      const product = action.payload;

      const favorited = state.favorites.find(
        (item) => item?.id === product?.id
      );

      if (!favorited) {
        // Not favorited, add to favorites list
        return {
          ...state,
          favorites: state.favorites.concat(product),
        };
      }
      // Otherwise return current state
      return state;

    case 'DELETE_FAVORITE_PRODUCT':
      const { product } = action.payload; // <-- get product from payload

      const favorited = state.favorites.find(
        (item) => item?.id === product?.id
      );

      if (favorited) {
        // Favorited, remove from favorites list
        return {
          ...state,
          favorites: state.favorites.filter((item)=> item.id !== product.id)
        };
      }
      // Otherwise return current state
      return state;
              
    case 'CLEAR':
      return { ...state, cart:[] };
           
    default:
      console.log("Unhandled action", { action });
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
const Favorite = () => {
  const { favorites, products } = useCart();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const unfavorite = (product) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "DELETE_FAVORITE_PRODUCT",
      payload: { product }, // <-- pass product in payload
    });
  };
 
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {!products.length ? (
        <View>
          <Text>Just add the items you would & place your order here.</Text>
        </View>   
      ) : (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <ScrollView>
            <View>
              {products.map((product) => (         
                <View key={product.id}>  
                  <Image source={product.image} />
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => unfavorite(product)}>
                    <Image source={icons.love} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              ))}
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```